# Windows For Loop with * Token

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get a loop to display the file/folder contents using a mix of specific (absolute full pathed) and * wildcard file/folder names, but my code is skipping the * wildcard searches. I'm using the DIR command to search since it works well with folders/dirs and files.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET VAR="c:\users\admin\documents\" "my files*" "*.MYO" "backups" "history.*" "History" "*.db" "all accounts.txt"
SET "ArchiveInclude="
FOR %%a IN (%VAR%) DO (
 IF "!a::!"=="!a!" (
  SET LookUpSet=DIR /ON /B /S "%%~a"
  FOR /F "Delims=" %%F IN ('!LookUpSet!') DO (
   SET ArchiveInclude=!ArchiveInclude! "%%~F"
  )
 ) ELSE ( SET ArchiveInclude=!ArchiveInclude! "%%~a" )
)
```

Unfortunately ArchiveInclude does not include any "my files*" "*.myo" or "history.*" search results. %%a never gets to process any string that contains the wildcard *.

I need ArchiveInclude to included all full path references to all files/folders specified eg

```
ECHO !ArchiveInclude!
"c:\users\admin\documents\" "c:\Users\User 3\my files here\" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\my files01.txt" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\my files02.txt" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\my files01.jpg" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\my files02.jpg" "c:\Users\User 2\Documents\My Account Files.MYO" "c:\Users\User 2\Documents\Business\Sales Accounts.MYO" "c:\Program Files\history.db" "c:\Program Files\history.txt" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\History\" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\Databases\afile.db" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\Databases\data.db" "c:\Users\User 1\Documents\Databases\last.db" "c:\Users\User 2\Documents\all accounts.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
FOR %%a IN (%VAR%) DO (
```

You've set VAR to a space-separated list of filenames, some with wildcards. When you have wildcards, the FOR command searches the current directory for any files that match the wildcard (type `FOR/?` for help.) That's not what you want. You don't want `FOR` to search at that point; you just want it to iterate over the given strings irrespective of what they contain.

Fortunately, you don't even have to use `FOR` because the `DIR` command can take multiple parameters. So you can just get rid of the `FOR` line completely and do this instead:

```
 SET LookUpSet=DIR /ON /B /S %VAR%
```

Comment: That will works well for single file/folder names + wildcards. However I would also need a way to exclude already specified (full pathed) folders/files from the DIR command, since DIR will list all contents of a full-pathed folder individually (which is not required). ie VAR="C:\users\admin\documents\" "my files*" ".myo" "backups" "history." "all accounts.txt". DIR command will list all the contents of "C:\users\admin\documents\", which is not required. Sorry for the lack of clarity in the OP, I've now updated it.